# How to get the max value of each group until it returns to zero using sQlite

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have the following table which has a date and a price field.
The price starts at zero and may increment with time.
I would like to group by highest price recorded in the period until the value returned to zero.

```
+----------------+------------+
|      price     |    date    |
+----------------+------------+
|              6 | 2016-12-18 |
|              5 | 2016-12-17 |
|              4 | 2016-12-16 |
|              3 | 2016-12-15 |
|              2 | 2016-12-14 |
|              1 | 2016-12-13 |
|              0 | 2016-12-12 |
|              1 | 2016-12-11 |
|              0 | 2016-12-10 |
|              0 | 2016-12-09 |
|              5 | 2016-12-08 |
|              4 | 2016-12-07 |
|              3 | 2016-12-06 |
|              2 | 2016-12-05 |
|              1 | 2016-12-04 |
|              0 | 2016-12-03 |
|              1 | 2016-12-02 |
|              0 | 2016-12-01 |
|              2 | 2016-11-30 |
|              1 | 2016-11-29 |
+----------------+------------+
```

Desired output :

```
+----------------+------------+
|      price     |    date    |
+----------------+------------+
|              6 | 2016-12-18 |
|              1 | 2016-12-11 |
|              5 | 2016-12-08 |
|              1 | 2016-12-02 |
|              2 | 2016-11-30 |
+----------------+------------+
```

How would one achieve that using sQlite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select      max(price)  as price
           ,max(date)   as date

from       (select      t1.price,t1.date,count(t2.date) as group_id

            from                    t t1

                        left join   t t2

                        on          t2.date <= t1.date
                                and t2.price = 0

            group by    t1.price,t1.date
            ) t

group by    group_id

having      max(price) <> 0

order by    date desc
```

---

```
+-------+------------+
| price | date       |
+-------+------------+
| 6     | 2016-12-18 |
+-------+------------+
| 1     | 2016-12-11 |
+-------+------------+
| 5     | 2016-12-08 |
+-------+------------+
| 1     | 2016-12-02 |
+-------+------------+
| 2     | 2016-11-30 |
+-------+------------+
```